# silverlight app

Tags: silverlight

Now we are developing the application in silverlight 3. I would like to implement the session time out in silverlight like asp.net session timeout. Please anyone give me the idea for that.

Thanks in Advance
Sekar

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DispatcherTimer to periodically poll the time since an activity has happened.  If the time has gone over the session time, then you can take action with the UI to inform the user their session has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions from Silverlight to javascript and viceversa.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav

Then you only have to use any technique around the web for trapping the session timeout in javascript and pass it to Silverlight.